# Where should I put the onChange method?

Tags: vue.js

Where to put the on-select method of iView Switch?

I use [iview Switch](https://www.iviewui.com/components/switch) as a component:

I use the render function:

```
  render: (h, params) => {
    return h('div', [
      // (vm, h, params, fn, btntext)
      h('i-switch',
        {
          props: {
            size:'large',
          },
          // onChange: function (value) {
          //   debugger
          //   context.change_product_item_status_by_user_own_count(params, value)
          // },
          on: {
            onChange: function (value) {
              debugger
            }
          }
        },
        [
          h('span', {slot: 'open'}, 'Open'),
          h('span', {slot: 'close'}, 'Close')
        ])
      ],
    )
  }
```

But all do not work.  where should I put the `onChange` method in the render function?

Answer (score 0):

From [Vue.js document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth):

```
  // Event handlers are nested under `on`, though
  // modifiers such as in `v-on:keyup.enter` are not
  // supported. You'll have to manually check the
  // keyCode in the handler instead.
  on: {
    click: this.clickHandler
  },
```

I saw the method is `on-change`, so there should be like this:

```
      on: {
        'on-change': function (value) {
          debugger
        }
      }
```